# gDebugger not working

Tags: debugging, opengl

I downloaded the last version of gDebugger (currently 5.8.1). But I can't make it works. I try to run the provided examples, but nothing happen.
I try to load the teapot example, but when I run it (F5), I just see a command line prompt which disappear immediately. (I also try to make the same actions as "Timothy Smith" described in http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/158943 in its first post, but the result was the same)

I'm on Win7 64 bits, with a GTX 470.

Edit: This is the error I get in the log:

```
[20:10:36]   [2495245290]   [ERROR]   [4448]   [gaAPIToSpyConnector::initialize]   [src\gaAPIToSpyConnector.cpp]   [217]   [Assertion failure (rcAPISocket)]
##   [20:10:36]   [2495245327]   [ERROR]   [4448]   [gaLaunchDebuggedProcess]   [src\gaGRApiFunctions.cpp]   [388]   [Assertion failure (rcAPIConnection)]
##   [20:10:36]   [2495821910]   [ERROR]   [4448]   [osPipeSocket::close]   [src\win32\osPipeSocket.cpp]   [124]   [Cannot close pipe (pipe type: osPipeSocketServer)]
##   [20:10:36]   [2495822046]   [ERROR]   [4448]   [osPipeSocket::close]   [src\win32\osPipeSocket.cpp]   [137]   [Cannot close pipe (pipe type: osPipeSocketServer)]
##   [20:10:36]   [2495822236]   [ERROR]   [4448]   [osPipeSocketServer::open]   [src\win32\osPipeSocketServer.cpp]   [76]   [Assertion failure (_incomingPipe != ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1))]
##   [20:10:36]   [2495822377]   [ERROR]   [4448]   [osPipeSocketServer::open]   [src\win32\osPipeSocketServer.cpp]   [97]   [Assertion failure (_outgoingPipe != ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1))]
##   [20:10:36]   [2495822453]   [ERROR]   [4448]   [gaAPIToSpyConnector::initialize]   [src\gaAPIToSpyConnector.cpp]   [217]   [Assertion failure (rcAPISocket)]
##   [20:10:36]   [2495822520]   [ERROR]   [4448]   [gaLaunchDebuggedProcess]   [src\gaGRApiFunctions.cpp]   [388]   [Assertion failure (rcAPIConnection)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gDebugger is now an AMD product and all the new versions are available on their developer [site](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-gdebugger/). Current version is 6.2.

*Edit:*
The tool is now called CodeXL and available [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/)

Comment: AMD calls it :  CodeXL

Comment: Thanks Event Horizon. At the time of the answer it was still called gDebugger. I added an update incase people find this in the future.

Comment: It's worth noting that **not all of the functionality from gDebugger works in CodeXL**. Which is sad as heck.

Comment: What does this mean for nVidia support? nVidia is still shipping gDebugger as part of their PerfKit, but it's impossible to start due to the gremedy license servers no longer existing. Is there any replacement tool for profiling OpenGL programs on nVidia GPUs?

Comment: @Dolda2000 This was the state of things in 2013.These days RenderDoc is an excellent alternative.

Comment: @StephanvandenHeuvel: Thanks for the referral, but RenderDoc is only a debugger and not a profiler though, no? What gDebugger appears to have had in particular was access to nVidia's hardware performance counters.